# How to map to interfaces using Model mapper?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am trying to use model mapper to map to an interface, and I am able to do it if I add this type map and converter to the mapper:

```
mapper.createTypeMap( ConcreteADomain.class, InterfaceApi.class )
                .setConverter( mappingContext -> mapper.map( mappingContext.getSource(), ConcreteAApi.class ) );
```

I hope the names are self-explanatory on what type of beans they are. With this, I need to do this for every new implementation.

If I do not add the mapping, I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

How do I let the mapper take care of mapping between the implementation and the interfaces? Is this even possible?

Comment: you need to configure AutoMapping in your mapper configuration. With AutoMapping, the mapper will attempt to map all known types automatically,

Comment: @RaushanKumar Can you please point me to any doc\reference where I can check what this automapping is for a model mapper? I am unable to find anything